# Is it possible to identify the programming language used to create a data file based on structure of content?

Tags: database, data-structures

I have a file that was intended to be read into a program for analysis.  I don't have the program that was to be used to analyze it and don't know what language was used to create it. The file extension is .DAT.  It appears to be a text file but the data format/structure makes it difficult to extract the useful information.  Here is a snippet of the first 56 rows of the file.  The file has 3,536 rows. If I know the language will I be able to transform the data to a format I can use?

```
{
"userName": "BOB       ",
"userAge": 25,
"userWeight": 185,
"userGender": "M",
"userHeight": "69",
"mID": "GB"
}
{
"workoutDate": {
    "Month": 8,
    "Day": 21,
    "Year": 2020
},
"distance": 3.9,
"finishTime": {
    "Hours": 17,
    "Minutes": 8
},
"pctAverageHeartRateInZone": 0.0,
"averageSpeed": 11.4,
"totalWorkoutTime": {
    "Hours": 0,
    "Minutes": 20
},
"averageWattsPerHour": 38.0,
"totalCalories": 55.0,
"avgHeartRate": 0.0,
"avgRpm": 46,
"avgLevel": 2
}
}
{
"workoutDate": {
    "Month": 8,
    "Day": 21,
    "Year": 2020
},
"distance": 0.2,
"finishTime": {
    "Hours": 16,
    "Minutes": 48
},
"pctAverageHeartRateInZone": 0.0,
"averageSpeed": 10.6,
"totalWorkoutTime": {
    "Hours": 0,
    "Minutes": 1
},
"averageWattsPerHour": 38.0,
"totalCalories": 4.0,
"avgHeartRate": 0.0,
"avgRpm": 36,
"avgLevel": 4
}
}
```

Comment: It appears to be *JSON*...

Answer (score 1):

This file is in a format called [Json](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), most languages will be able to parse json data relatively easily like python's [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) package or Java's [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library.

Json is not tied to any one language so you cannot determine what language was used to serialize the data into the file.